# What would this look like in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Hey everyone I'm trying to get a clearer understanding of LINQ.  I have a set of foreach loops that I use to loop through a list of IDs that I then compare to a list of object IDs and then add them to a 3rd list that holds the result or the comparing.  I was wondering what this bit of code would look like in LINQ
list1 -> List of int Ids
list2 -> List of Objects

```
foreach (var mId in list1)
{
   foreach (var m in list2)
   {
      if (m.Obj.Id== mId)
      {
        result.Add(m);
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to return duplicated ids?

Comment: I realize now it allows for duplicates but actually it shouldn't it was miss by me sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, that is the loop logic to perform a join. Using query syntax (which is more readable) you could do:

```
var result = from mId in list1
             join m in list2 on m.Obj.Id equals mId
             select m;
```

Or, if lambda's are your thing:

```
var result = list1.Join(list2, 
                        mId => mId, 
                        m => m.Obj.Id,
                        (mId, m) => m);
```

Comment: +1 with the note that for your example to be perfectly equivalent to the OP's code, you need a `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.

Comment: This could behave subtly different from the original. 1) It should perform better, which is a plus. 2) The result could be different. In the original, if `mId` is present twice, `m` could end up in result twice. That should be preserved here. In the original, if `m.Obj.Id` is present twice, it would be in the result once. Here, it would be twice. If an element is in each list twice, you'd get 4 results here. In the original, just 2. Are these differences important? Possible? That's for the question asker to determine.

Comment: Assuming `m` had proper overloads of `Equals\GetHashCode` (or a valid `IEqualityComparer` could be provided), utilizing `list2.Distinct()` prior to the join should preserve the results of the original code snippet (if duplicates are a possibility*).

Answer (score 2):

It would look something like this:

```
var result = list2.Where(i => list1.Contains(i.Obj.Id));
```

Comment: +1. This actually gets the correct behavior (which the other answers don't), while vastly clarifying the intent of the code. "I want all the items in `list2` whose ID is in `list1`."

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = list1.Join(list2, x => x, x => x.Obj.Id, (outer, inner) => inner);
```